# Batch renaming of files using regular expression in Unix

Tags: unix, regex, sed, rename

I have several thousand files of the form:

[8-digit number]_[number I want]_S60491_I129111.dcm.

I wish to remove everything except the number I want, and use that as its name. In Ruby, I can get to that value with the regular expression `/^.*_(\d+)_S60491_I12911.dcm/`, but I'm having trouble trying to translate that to a `sed` expression that allows me to substitute the full filename for just that number between the underscores.

Is there a way using `sed` or other basic Bash commands to do what I want? If it helps, the number I want is just a counter (i.e. it runs from 1 to 2100), and the prefix 8-digit number happens to result in the files being listed in correct order (i.e. from file 1 to file 2100), so I may be over-thinking things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me: `for a in * ; do mv "$a" $(echo "$a" | cut -d'_' -f 2) ; done`

```
toad:/home/hennes/work/foo>ls -l
total 0
-rw-------  1   users  0 Jan 23 22:19 12345678_023454_S60491_I129111.dcm
-rw-------  1   users  0 Jan 23 22:19 12345678_123454_S60491_I129111.dcm
-rw-------  1   users  0 Jan 23 22:19 12345678_123456_S60491_I129111.dcm

toad:/home/hennes/work/foo>for a in * ; do mv $a $(echo $a | cut -d'_' -f 2) ; done

toad:/home/hennes/work/foo>ls -l
total 0
-rw-------  1   users  0 Jan 23 22:23 023454
-rw-------  1   users  0 Jan 23 22:23 123454
-rw-------  1   users  0 Jan 23 22:23 123456
```

`for a in *` selects all files.  If there are more files a *.dcm can be used instead.

mv (move) changes the filename

from $a (the filename select in for)

to  field2 of the name, with `_` used a field delimiter.

Note that this script will move the files, so the old file names will be lost. You can use 'cp' rather than 'mv' to make a copy instead.

If you want to keep the extension then add it after the -f 2).
 E.g.
`for a in * ; do cp $a $(echo $a | cut -d'_' -f 2).dcm ; done`

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool commonly named [rename](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) or `prename` installed on most systems.  On my Debian/Ubuntu systems this comes as part of Perl.  It allows you to use Perl style regular expressions to manipulate filenames however you like.

Your command would probably look like this.  I do suggest you pass the `--no-act` option and examine the output before you actually commit to making any changes.

```
prename 's/^.*_(\d+)_S60491_I12911.dcm/$1/' *
```

Comment: I found `rename` and `prename` come up a bit when trying to search for a solution myself, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be on the server at work I'm using for this (it looks like it's a version of Red Hat). Definitely something I'll look in to on my home computer though.

Comment: It is a pretty simple perl script.  You could almost certainly snag a copy from some other box, if you have Perl installed.

Answer (score 1):

Since we  know the format of the names and none contain spaces:

```
for a in * ; do
   mv $a $(echo $a | sed 's/[^_]*_//;s/_S60491_I129111.dcm//')
done
```

Comment: Sorry about the edit/rollback, I saw this would break on spaces but missed your disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get this done. But since you asked for `sed`, this would do:

> ls *dcm | sed 's/^([0-9]{8}_([0-9]*)_S60491_I129111.dcm)/mv \1
>   \2 /g' | bash

The first bit of the pattern selects 8-digit numbers, then you look for any digits (since you didn't mention what size the second number was) and then your trailing sequence. `\1` and `\2` refer to the contents of the outer and inner escaped parentheses `\(...\)`. You can replace `bash` by any shell in this case.

The GNU extensions of sed would allow you to do also:

> ls *dcm | sed 's/^([0-9]{8}_([0-9]+)_S60491_I129111.dcm)/mv \1
>   \2 /g' | bash

where `+` allows for matching one or more, where `*` matches zero or more, which causes problems for `12345678__S60491_I129111.dcm`.